# How to get the serviceWorker flag in angular-cli.json?

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have an existing project in angular, to which I want to add a service worker for making it progressive-web-app. I use angular 5.2.11 and because of old cli I can't use the `ng add` command. So I started manually, I installed:

```
$npm install @angular/service-worker@5.2.11
$npm install @angular/pwa@0.10.3
```

What else do I need to install in order to get the serviceWorker flag in angular-cli.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your are using angular 5.2.1, your CLI must be at least 1.6 and you can do the following:

```
$ npm install @angular/service-worker
$ ng set apps.0.serviceWorker=true
```

This last command sets the `serviceWorker` flag in `angular-cli.json`.

You can then configure your app module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then you can add the service-worker configuration file `ngsw-worker.js` in the `src` directory:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

Check this article for more details: https://alligator.io/angular/service-workers/

Hope this helps.